# Gerrit Web UI URL

Tags: user-interface, web, gerrit

I'm quite new to Gerrit.I'm getting Permisson denied(public key) while running ssh command .I want to add rsa key to my Gerrit profile.But I'm not able to take the Web UI.I tried localhost:29418 But nothing come up.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Gerrit web ui is served on a dedicated port, defined in `gerrit.config` in the `listenUrl` line

Answer (score 0):

If you used the -b batch mode you can probably find the site on `http:// localhost :8080`
The first user to login will have automatically administration rights and you should be able to enter a userid and ssh key. You need to then use this userid plus the ssh key to connect.

`ssh -p 29418``userid@ 127.0.0.1` `gerrit`

This should then show you the gerrit help.